# ASP.Net - Loop all HTML components in the current page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

I wish I could go all the elements of an ASP.Net page (HTML elements) and manipulate its text property / value. How could I do that?

I've been checking, and the property this.Page.Form.Controls apparently gets all the elements, but I would only page elements that caught the event. Does anyone have any idea.

I'll put an example of code that I'm currently studying and trying adpater for my needs.

Thanks

```
 string x = String.Empty;
 string y = String.Empty;

 foreach (Control ctrl in this.Page.Form.Controls){
     if (ctrl is TextBox){
        x += ((TextBox)(ctrl)).ID + ((TextBox)(ctrl)).Parent + "\n";
     } else {
        y += ctrl.GetType().Name + ctrl.GetType().Namespace + "\n";
     }
 }
```

Obs.: I am using some components of the Telerik components.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to achieve is evident from your question. You talk about filtering out the elements that *caught the event* - what event? You also say you want to do this in order to manipulate the Text property, but your code doesn't seem to involve any of that. Also, a heads up: `Form.Controls` doesn't give you all the elemnts of a page recursively, i.e. if there's a PlaceHolder that has `.Controls` of its own, `Form.Controls` will only yield the PlaceHolder.

Comment: In the example above, I'm just trying to read the ID of components, so as to find the perfect code to get what I want so much. Well, briefly, I search all objects of a form. When I get it, and somehow get to know the type of each one, I can then modify the programming to handle each element. Thanks

Comment: I still don't think the question is clear. If all you want to do is find all the controls in a form, then what more than `this.Page.Form.Controls` do you want (disregarding the recursion issue I mentioned earlier, as that doesn't seem to be a central concern of yours)?  And if you want to *somehow get to know the type of each one*, well, that's what you're doing in your example, through `is TextBox` for testing for a type, or `GetType()` for simply retrieving the type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls on a page are stored in a tree data structure.  You could use a recursive method to do this:

```
    private void SetText(ControlCollection controls, String textToSet)
    {
        foreach(Control c in controls)
        {
            if (c is ITextControl)
                ((ITextControl)c).Text = textToSet;

            if (c.HasControls())
                SetText(c.Controls, textToSet);
        }
    }
```

and you would call this method somewhere like let's say, in the OnPreRender Event (to make sure that you get all controls that have been added to the page) and pass the Page.Controls ControlCollection:

```
    protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);
        SetText(Page.Controls, "new text");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll have a stab at an answer, although I'm not sure it's what you're after (see my comments to the question).

If what you want to do is to quickly handle all the `TextBoxes` of a form (say) in one manner, and all of its `DropDownLists` in another manner, then what you're looking for may be `OfType`

```
DoSomethingWithAllTextBoxes( Page.Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() );
DoSomethingWithAllDropDownLists( Page.Form.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>() );

private void DoSomethingWithAllTextBoxes( IEnumerable<TextBox> textboxes) {
    foreach(TextBox txt in textboxes) {
       txt.Text = "Modified";
    }
}
```

If you're looking for event binding, you could run code like this one in `OnInit`

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {

    foreach(TextBox txt in Page.Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() ) {
       txt.OnTextChanged += TextChangedEventListener;
    }        

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the elements you want to an event and then act of them when its fired.  This example is for demonstration but you could define a custom event.

**ASPX:**

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
        ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
       ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
 protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
     //do something
 }
```

Comment: will work, but I think there must be some method more flexible. Thanks.

Comment: What kindof "event" are you looking to capture? You could always use jQuery selectors and then post them all to process.